# How to change the default color themes in SWT applications?

Tags: java, colors, widget, swt, themes

When creating a eclipse plugin with SWT,(this is not using RCP) it seems that the colors of swt widgets change from one pc to another. So it depends on the pc's color settings. I want to be color theme same at everywhere. It should not change by pc to pc. I am not meaning setting colors manually for each widget.

Comment: Base SWT does not have themes, the controls use whatever colors the native controls use.

Comment: @greg-449 so what is the solution for my problem?

Comment: If your plugin is used in Eclipse 4.x then the [Eclipse 4 CSS styling](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html) will be used.

Comment: I want to be color theme same at everywhere. color should not change according to the os. how to do that. that is my question.

Comment: You will have to set the colors of each control.

Comment: @greg-449 - can you please answer this question too- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270276/how-to-set-lines-visible-in-swt-table-including-widgets-in-cells