# How to set lines visible in SWT table, including widgets in cells?

Tags: java, widget, swt, border

I created a table with SWT and I included SWT widgets such as Label, Text in the table cells using TableEditor. But now my problem is, the outlines of the table cells are not visible now. I want to make visible all the borders of columns and rows. How to do it? Setting `table.setLinesVisible(true)` is not a success!

```java
       Table table = new Table(detailArea, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
       table.setLinesVisible(true);
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
          column.setWidth(100);
       }

        TableItem x1= new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        TableEditor editorw = new TableEditor(table);

        Label lblName =new Label(table, SWT.NONE);
        lblName.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        lblName.setText("Language");           
        editorw.grabHorizontal = true;
        editorw.setEditor(lblName, x1, 0);

        editorw = new TableEditor(table);
        Text txtLang = new Text(table, SWT.BORDER);
        editorw.grabHorizontal = true;
        editorw.setEditor(txtLang, x1, 1);                  

        editorw = new TableEditor(table);
        Label lblReference = new Label(table,
                SWT.NONE);
        lblReference.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        lblReference.setText("Value");
        editorw.grabHorizontal = true;
        editorw.setEditor(lblReference, x1, 2);

        editorw = new TableEditor(table);
        Text txtValue= new Text(table, SWT.BORDER);
        editorw.grabHorizontal = true;
        editorw.setEditor(txtValue, x1, 3);

        /////table row 2
        TableItem x2= new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        editorw = new TableEditor(table);

        Label lblName2 =new Label(table, SWT.NONE);
        lblName2.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        lblName2.setText("Language");           
        editorw.grabHorizontal = true;
        editorw.setEditor(lblName2, x2, 0);

        editorw = new TableEditor(table);
        Text txtLang2 = new Text(table, SWT.BORDER);
        editorw.grabHorizontal = true;
        editorw.setEditor(txtLang2, x2, 1);

        editorw = new TableEditor(table);
        Label lblReference2 = new Label(table,
                  SWT.NONE);
        lblReference2.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        lblReference2.setText("Value");
        editorw.grabHorizontal = true;
        editorw.setEditor(lblReference2, x2, 2);

        editorw = new TableEditor(table);
        Text txtValue2= new Text(table, SWT.BORDER);
        editorw.grabHorizontal = true;
        editorw.setEditor(txtValue2, x2, 3);


        table.setLinesVisible(true);
```

Following is the current output:

[image]

Comment: Do you actually want to draw a border around each cell (one arnound 'Language', one around the text widget, etc.) or should the border be drawn around 'Language' and the adjacent text widget and another around 'Value' and the adjacent text widget?

Comment: I want to draw borders around each cell.

Comment: And I want to accomplish one more thing. I want to know how to add padding for widgets in the cells. For example, u can see that the "Value" Label should come few more pixels to the right (so that the formatting would be more nice). In other words there should be more gap between that "Value" Label and the left Text box. How to do that?

Comment: hi greg...isn't there any solution in swt for this as u know?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the editor widgets (label and text) into a `Composite`. The composite can be given a border and a layout that can specify a margin:

```
Composite composite = new Composite( table, SWT.BORDER );
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
composite.setLayout( layout );
Label label = new Label( composite, SWT.NONE );
GridData gridData = new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true );
gridData.verticalIndent = 2;
gridData.horizontalIndent = 2;
label.setLayoutData( gridData );
editor.setEditor( composite, item, 0 );
```

A different approach might be [owner draw table items](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html) In particular see the `EraseItem` event that can be used to draw the background. However I am afraid that since you cannot influence the `TableEditor`'s layout, the owner-drawn borders will be hidden by the editor widgets.

Note that this approach (neither your initial nor the composite-wrapped one) will not scale well for several hundret rows. For each row, 4 or 8 widgets will be created. Depending on the client computers performance it will slow down when creating several hundret widgets and eventually run out of handles.

Comment: I don't think setting margin would work. because I want to make the composites (u have created) fill completely inside a cell. If I set a margin to a that composite there would be a gaps between each cell borders.  that is not I want. I want to add padding inside composite.

Comment: And isn't there any other solution rather that using extra composites to make the cell borders visible?

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga What's wrong with an extra `Composite` if it's that what it takes to show borders?

Comment: I am actually creating a quite a big table and so having to create a composite for each cell where there is a lot of number of cells, is really cumbersome. And I hope there should be a way to show cell borders as a major intention of a table is showing cell borders, dividing columns and rows by lines well.